# Regex returning value prefixed with "="

Tags: python, regex, string, parsing, properties-file

I'm trying to return `My.Name` from the string: `one.test.two=My.Name`

As I understand I will need to use the `?<!` operator.  The problem is that the "=" is left in the match using the following regex:

```
import re
print(re.search("(?<!(one.test.two=))?=(.*)", "one.test.two=My.Name"))
```

ie i return `=My.Name`, as opposed to `My.Name`.  Please help me to understand why this is happening, and why I am not getting the desired result.

Comment: Try... `re.search("(?<=one.test.two=)(.*)", "one.test.two=My.Name"))`. If this is the result you are looking for, I can explain.

Comment: I am not even sure you need anything more complicated than re.search("one.test.two=(.*)","one.test.two=My.Name")

Comment: @ShawnTabrizi don't forget to get result by `.group(1)` in that case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a simpler regex:

```
re.search(r'.+=(.*)', 'one.test.two=My.Name').group(1)
```

We're only interested in whatever it's to the right of the `=` character.